# What is causing this error in my code: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

What is wrong with this snippet that is causing the error:

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime bday = DateTime.Parse(ctxtBirthday.Text);
        int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
        ctxtAge.Text = age.ToString();
```

`ctxtBirthday.Text` contains for example the date: `1978-03-08`

`ctxtAge.Text` is where I want the age result to be.

The error when the `.aspx` loads is:

> System.FormatException
>
> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: May help if you told us exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be issue with your culture.

You can use `ParseExact()` instead of `Parse()`:

```
DateTime bday = DateTime.ParseExact(ctxtBirthday.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**OR**

You can set needed culture in `Parse()` method:

```
DateTime bday = DateTime.Parse(ctxtBirthday.Text, CultureInfo.YourCulture); // use needed culture
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get the same error. I am using NpgSql could that be causing the issue?

Comment: @TommyMcGee, your code is plain C#, NpgSql can't be problem here

Comment: @TommyMcGee, are you sure the text in your textbox is correct date string? Maybe there are additional spaces or something else?

Comment: Yes you were correct, my text box was displaying the incorrect format. matching sure the format was line with the code got everything working.